# Proving that a programming language is not regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I am wanting to show that the C programming language is not a regular
language.

The alphabet would be ASCII characters and
comments, strings, char can contain arbitrary characters.

Would I best approach this potentially with a pumping lemma?
There's not really constraints or anything, this is more of a creative
concept :)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the pumping lemma will work fine, as would Myhill–Nerode.  There's a hint below; mouse-over to see it but try without.

> Use the fact that C requires braces to be well-nested.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learned Myhill-Nerode yet, but thank you!